# Check to see if several files exist in a directory

Tags: c#

It's a simple question but I can't find an optimal solution.

I have a method:

```
private void MyMethod(string directory, string[] filenames)
{
 ...
}
```

I don't know the filenames length, it can be different. And in MyMethod I need to check that all files from filenames is exist in directory.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you share what did you try so far with results?

Comment: If just one file doesn't exist, what should happen?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried doing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`, `System.IO.Path.Combine`(to combine the directory and file-name) and [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool allFilesExist = filenames.All(f => File.Exists(Path.Combine(directory, f)));
```